# How to pass icons of react-icon in before element content using styled component?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, next.js, styled-components

Follow my style using awesome font:

Styled:

```
.bar-fields-car:before {font-family: "Font Awesome 6 Free"; content: '\f007';}
```

I want to consume icons from react-icons instead of awesome fonts using styled-component.

I would like to know if there is a possibility to pass the react-icons incons in my styled component

Comment: Hello. Can you please detail more your post? We are willing to help you, but with an unclear request we cannot help much. Thanks

Comment: Also your question does not need to be entirely in bold.   If projected that way .. It's considered "yelling" and nobody likes to be yelled at.